# How to flatten json array using typescript and Convert it as object

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to convert a json array as a flat json using typescript.
I have a json as below:

```
"Fields" : [
    {
    "FieldName" : "xyz";
    "FieldValue" : {
     "Contents": {
      " Company": "ABC"
    }
    }
    }
    ]
```

I have to convert as below:

```
"xyz" :  {
      "Contents": {
      " Company": "ABC"
     }
    }
Here Fields should be replaced with "xyz", FieldName and FieldValue should need to be removed.
```

Help me to achieve this using typescript.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to work with that first item in your array just rearrange the data with something the following.

```js
const json = JSON.stringify({
  Fields: [
    {
      FieldName: "xyz",
      FieldValue: {
        Contents: {
          " Company": "ABC"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});

const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);

const expectedOutput = {
  [parsedJson.Fields[0].FieldName]: parsedJson.Fields[0].FieldValue
};

console.log(expectedOutput);
```